# How to get the Push id of current user in Firebase Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have generated the push id of the user who have sign up.

```
String id=databaseUser.push().getKey();
```

How I can get this id when the user signs in?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store that id in the database as a property of your User object but a more elegant way would be to use the `uid` and not that random key provided by the `push()` method. So once you are authenticated, you can get the `uid`, using the following line of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Comment: How can i retrive the whole node using this uid??

Comment: This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349364/get-user-node-from-firebase-using-uid-android