# get user node from Firebase using the uid in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get the user node using uid generated through:

```
     String uid=
     FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

[The JSON is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KPBh.png)

Comment: Send a pic of your FB database structure
So that we can know how to help you access the particular node

Comment: I have already added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this answer according to your request from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348025/how-to-get-the-push-id-of-current-user-in-firebase-android/51348598?noredirect=1#comment89671212_51348598) but I see that although you are getting the `uid` from the `FirebaseUser` object, you are not using it at all. You are still using that random unique key provided by the `push()` method. So if you want to use the `uid`, your database structure should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- users
         |
         --- uid
              |
              --- email: "nicefawad1@gmail.com"
              |
              --- uid: "uid"
              |
              --- name: "fawad"
```

See, I have used the `uid` that is coming as a result from the following line of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

In order to read this data, you have two options. The first one would be as @Gastón Saillén explained in his answer using a model class, or in a more simpler way using the `String` class. So to get the name of a specific user, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your logcat will be: `fawad`.

Comment: yes i got the result actually i was using wrong method to take the uid.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a POJO object class in order to get the atributes from that current uid user

to do that first create a class with your user variables, i will call this `UserPojo.class`

```
public class userPojo {

 private String email;
    private String id;
    private String name;


    public userPojo() {

    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

 }
```

And then just iterate through that node and get your values this way

first declare your database reference

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
```

then inside `onCreate()`

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); //root reference to the database
```

then just get the values inside the reference

```
 mDatabase.child("collion").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        UserPojo user = snapShot.getValue(UserPojo.class);
        //get your values inside that uid
         String name = polla.geName();
         String email = polla.getEmail();
         String id = polla.getId();

          Log.e("Data: " , "" + name + "" + email+""+id);

           }


      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
      }
    });
```

thats all, any question feel free to ask

Comment: i use to toast the email of the user but does not show anything. other thing is that the uid does not match with the Push().getId

Comment: i got null in result but by using String.class i got the result